# git post-receive hook to update multiple servers

Tags: git, deployment, githooks

I'm using [git post-receive hook](https://github.com/jollyroger/vcs-hooks/blob/master/git/server-sync/post-receive) to deploy versions of the web application from three branches (master, staging, and stable) on three servers (development, testing and production). The pairing between branches and servers is currently hard-coded in the script. However I'd like to remove this restriction and make this hook possible to manage unlimited quantity of branches. It can be done in the following way:

- move all per-branch config options to some separate files, for example `.git/???/<branch_name>`
- the main script will check if such file is available for every branch, source it and then deploy on the remote server using configuration parameters from that file.

However I don't know where exactly in `.git` directory can I place such files. Or maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options, as far as I can tell:

- Use a stronger convention for server naming, so that config isn't necessary, beyond the base domain name. Leave that in the script. (That is, branchX -> branchX-deploy.example.com.)
- Put a config file wherever you feel like in the .git directory, like you suggested. If it's not a filename git cares about, it'll never notice it. I'm not sure *why* you'd want to do this, though.
- Put it in .git/config. Git lets you define arbitrary config parameters of the form `branch.<name>.foo`. (I have no idea if this is a feature or an oversight. It's not documented, as far as I know.) In your case, something like `branch.master.deploy_server` set to `development.example.com`. Your script could then just go through *all* branches, and check whether that config option is set or not. (Use `git config --get`.)
- Put a config file in your repository. This seems a lot better than hiding it away. You might as well track the settings. If necessary, provide a way to override them - supply a different config file as an argument, supply individual branches/servers as options, interactive prompts, whatever suits you.

Personally, I'd probably do the last one. Tracking settings, even if they're only default settings, can't hurt you.

Comment: I'd like to have at least username, hostname and target directory so only naming branches will not work. I also don't want to place such config in the source code tree since it has nothing to deal with sources and I don't want to bother developers with unnecessary knowledge. It seems I will be using `.git/config` since it is the most clean solution for now.

Comment: For the record, I completely disagree that .git/config is the most clean. It's untracked.

Comment: But It's really what I am looking for. This file shouldn't be tracked and available for a developer anyway since deployment is not a developer's (as a role) task. The responsibility of tracking the file lays on administrator and it's tools only. I've [implemented](https://github.com/jollyroger/vcs-hooks/tree/master/git/server-sync/) this solution, maybe it can be useful for someone except me.